# Meteor autoform submit and modal dismissal

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

Using autoform I am trying to create a modal that will dismiss on submit only if the fields are valid. If the fields are not valid I do not want the modal to dismiss. In the format shown below it will always dismiss even when the values are not valid.

```
<template name="insertForm">
  {{#autoForm schema=schema id="insertForm" type="method" meteormethod="newC"}}
  <fieldset>
    {{> afQuickField name="Name"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="Stuff"}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#formModal" data-toggle="modal">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Hook](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks) to do this. this sample code may help you to understand :

```
var insertFormhook = {
    onSuccess: function(update, result) {
        if(result){

            // ...

            Modal.hide('insertForm');
        }
    }
}

AutoForm.addHooks('insertForm',insertFormhook);
```

Basically i am using [peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) which gives me easy to use bootstrap 3 modals.

Cheers...